# 13.10 login Background without unity

Tags: unity, 13.10, cinnamon

I want to change my login screen background (and keep the dots). But I upgraded to cinnamon 2.0 a day ago and then to 13.10 earlier today. I recently became aware of the issue with cinnamon 2.0 and unity on 13.10. This normally would not matter to me since I use cinnamon instead but the only way I know of to change the login screen background is to change unity background. Also all of my backgrounds are jpgs not pngs (in case anyone was gonna say the replace /usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntu-warty.png) and for some reason gimp has issues so converting them is not currently possible for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope Ubuntu-Tweak will solve your issue**

- First install latest ubuntu-tweak 0.85 by execute this command in terminal:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
  ```
- Once installed open it from dash and go to <kbd>Tweaks</kbd> tab.
- Open **Login Settings** option under **Startup**.
- First click <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button located top-right side, give password.
- After Unlock it will clear to you what to do. i,e If you want to set same login background as the current desktop background you have to click : <kbd>Set the background as the current desktop background</kbd> button. or else if you want to change a different one you have to click the big square button above to it.

Hope it will help you to resolve your issue.. Reply if something goes wrong..